# Save order when using top-nested Kusto operator

Tags: excel, pivot, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to produce a hierarchical aggregation by using top-nested Kusto operator for export to xlsx and works well but i'm loosing my default order by "Class" and "Date" fields by using query:

```
Test | top-nested 25 of Class by sum(Value),  top-nested 25 of Date by sum(Value)
```

my data in db [xlsx file](https://fex.net/s/skkposc)

[image: my data in db looks like in this file]

expected result on **this image** (same as above but Order by Class)
query:

```
Test | where (tolower(Class) == tolower('Väganläggning'))| summarize sum(Value) by Date | take 25
```

[image]

but i'm getting data with strange order for "Date" and "Class" like on this exported **xlsx file** (first "Date" 2029 year instead 2009 and so on)

[image]

Seems i need query like this

`Test | where Class == prev(Class) | top-nested 25 of Class by sum(Value),  top-nested 25 of Date by sum(Value)`

but i'm not experienced in Kusto, so need help guys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last dimension column goes to the `Values` section in the Excel Pivot.
The rest of the columns goes to the `Rows` section.

```
// Generate data sample. Not part of the solution.
let Test = materialize
(
    range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 
    | extend Class = strcat("Class-", tostring(toint(rand(10))))
            ,Date  = startofday(ago(1d*rand(30)))
            ,Value = rand()
            ,Dim1  = strcat("Dim1-", tostring(toint(rand(10))))
            ,Dim2  = strcat("Dim2-", tostring(toint(rand(10))))
            ,Dim3  = strcat("Dim3-", tostring(toint(rand(10))))
);
// Solution starts here.
Test
| top-nested 4 of Class by sum(Value)
 ,top-nested 3 of Date  by sum(Value)
 ,top-nested 2 of Dim1  by sum(Value)
 ,top-nested 2 of Dim2  by sum(Value)
 ,top-nested 2 of Dim3  by sum(Value) 
| order by aggregated_Class ,Class asc
          ,aggregated_Date  ,Date  asc
          ,aggregated_Dim1  ,Dim1 asc
          ,aggregated_Dim2  ,Dim2 asc
          ,aggregated_Dim3  ,Dim3 asc
| project-rename Values = aggregated_Dim3
| project-away aggregated_*
```

| Class | Date | Dim1 | Dim2 | Dim3 | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class-1 | 2022-05-10T00:00:00Z | Dim1-2 | Dim2-8 | Dim3-8 | 5.1418120760105817 |
| Class-1 | 2022-05-10T00:00:00Z | Dim1-2 | Dim2-8 | Dim3-4 | 4.8139672995169027 |
| Class-1 | 2022-05-10T00:00:00Z | Dim1-2 | Dim2-5 | Dim3-4 | 3.6333999871855704 |
| Class-1 | 2022-05-10T00:00:00Z | Dim1-2 | Dim2-5 | Dim3-0 | 3.5165481405530339 |
| Class-1 | 2022-05-10T00:00:00Z | Dim1-6 | Dim2-9 | Dim3-3 | 3.526092609498761 |

(Only a sample of the output)

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WTTU/DMAyG75X6H6ydOtSta8sNcQKJGxcQV2QWrwtqkyrxBEP78eRjk0onlc2XNNbjV/brtCjgiRQZZAKBjGCx61tawrNm6NEw6A3wlsDqdsdSq2WatMTwSpbhHjpXZyS28ofSJEsTcGFQNQQSNkZ3UAJrKFchwDL1LhOxA9A3kxLw0KK1TsuyWSNns3BfzHJX6VJSNRlrqThzuiIrV3MXUeEU+aPvPii4hvVG4D7DRmeluAk19eq85A3bHbmSAJzpya6EQUf+fl1DsqtGAtW1AvVIoP5PYH6XJkUBL8dFRTcsbMmQW5pfWJocnEK/UO6bBNz63Ub3P/Zgd10WXPG95AOs9li0eAqrAhacuwSrLsPqEQZ+Bm0EGZ/HpjHUuNbEe5wjjwfa9dDQfMDFQY5PZooLk8SnMI1Vp4VPY/VprQE7QG/0J615YUhhRxDG87/BqGqI4hf+mfnmFwLHSqO+AwAA)

[image: Excel Pivot]

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Thanks but still have incrorrect order. In Visualize have disordered and in xlsx as well -they want imposible...
i will propose them to use asc order for children when expand fields and when export all data to xlsx then we will get syncronized order in Visualize and for exported data in Excel.
Thanks for your help

Comment: In this case I'm not sure I got the required order. What would it be the example I gave?
P.S. Please also consider to upvote :-)

Comment: please take mine https://fex.net/s/skkposc
check order:

 `Test | order by  Class`;

now order is correct: 1 - 2009, 2 -2018 (like on second picture).
but if i do query

` | order by  Class
  | top-nested 25 of Class by sum(Value),  top-nested 25 of Date by sum(Value) `

i will get wrong order: 1-2029, 2-2028, so on (third picture).

Comment: Your Excel does not contain hierarchy, not a clear order. I'm really struggling here to understand what your needs are here.

Comment: i need same order as in my xlsx file but i lose this default order  when use top-nested operator

Comment: **What is the logic behind that order?** `Class Date Value
Väganläggning 8/1/2009 768739212
Väganläggning 12/1/2018 36611192642
Väganläggning 12/1/2013 36558443381
Väganläggning 9/1/2010 501787878.8
Väganläggning 7/1/2010 1794358029`

Comment: just regular sum and group:
| summarize Value=sum(Value) by Class,Date

Comment: i know that task seems strange, but in visualize user can expand field and export to xlsx this field with childs. But they wont as well to export all fields with all childs in SAME order and i don't know what to do - summarize  has own sorter and top-nested has own sorter

Comment: within a table, records do not have order. The result of a query does not have an order, unless explicitly defined. Without an explicit order, the result of a query is dependent on internals and can be changed between engine versions or even executions.